Potentials and orientation-preserving isometries
I'm trying to prove the following

Lemma: If $U,V \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ are open, and are equipped with
conformal metrics $g_U=\lambda^2dzd\bar{z}$ and $g_V=\mu^2dzd\bar{z}$.
If $f:U \rightarrow V$ is an orientation-preserving isometry, and $F:V
 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a potential for the metric $g_V$, then $F
 \circ f$ is a potential for the metric $g_U$.

It's sufficient to prove that $\Delta(F\circ f) = \lambda^2$.
By chain rule and product rule,
$$\frac{\partial^2(F \circ f)}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2(F)}{\partial x^2} \cdot \frac{\partial(f_1)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial(F)}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial^2(f_1)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2(F)}{ \partial x \partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial(f_2)}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial(F)}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial^2(f_2)}{\partial x^2},$$
$$\frac{\partial^2(F \circ f)}{\partial y^2} =\frac{\partial^2(F)}{ \partial y \partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial(f_1)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial(F)}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial^2(f_1)}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2(F)}{\partial y^2} \cdot \frac{\partial(f_2)}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial(F)}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial^2(f_2)}{\partial y^2} ,$$
and by Cauchy-Riemann equations,
$$\Delta(F \circ f) = \frac{\partial^2(F \circ f)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2(F \circ f)}{\partial y^2} = (\frac{\partial^2(F)}{\partial x^2} +\frac{\partial^2(F)}{\partial y^2}) \frac{\partial(f_1)}{\partial x} =\Delta(F) \cdot \frac{\partial(f_1)}{\partial x} = \mu^2 \cdot \frac{\partial(f_1)}{\partial x},$$
and I can't see how to continue from there.
I would like to use that $\mu^2(f(p)) |f'(p)|^2 = \lambda^2(p)$, for every $p \in U$; but the coefficient in the last equality is not appropriate. What am I doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.
